# JQ: Generate txt file with json information

Tags: json, text, jq, dynamically-generated

I have the following Json:

```
[{
    "_id": {
            "$oid": "59c3942baeef22b03fa573d2"
    },
    "client_id": "test@test.com",
    "name": "Windows Client"
},
{
    "_id": {
            "$oid": "59c3942baeef22b03fa573d2"
    },
    "client_id": "test2@test2.com",
    "name": "Linux Client"
}]
```

I would like to output the following:

```
mongo_customers,customer=test@test.com
mongo_customers,customer=test2@test.com
```

I've tryed the following but it doesn't work:

```
jq -n -R \
  --slurpfile mongo mongo.json \
'
  $mongo[][].client_id] as $mongo_ids
  "mongo_customers,customer="($mongo_ids)
'
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jq -r '.[] | "mongo_customers,customer=\(.client_id)"' mongo.json
```

There are many other possibilities. If you want to be absolutely sure the result will be valid CSV, then you might want to use the `@csv` filter.